# Nexus 7 2013 USB connection failed

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, usb, nexus-7

I've used my Nexus to test CM and other ROMs before; but now with 6.0.1, I simply can't get it to work with USB neither under Windows or Linux.

On Lubuntu it says:

```
[  36.853678] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd 
[  36.965697] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[  37.181684] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[  37.941764] usb 3-1: Device not responding to setup address.
```

On Windows 10, it is Unknown USB Device (Device Descriptor Request Failed).

I've tried 3 cables and 3 other devices (Windows Phone, Android), everything else is working. I've opened up and cleaned the USB port, nothing happened. The device charges successfully.

I have installed all Google Drivers and whatnot, adb and fastboot doesn't see the device - not in normal mode, not in recovery mode.

If I connect the device, it will not show the USB connection options on Android.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turned out it was a cable issue. still amazing - all other usb2 devices worked correctly, but the nexus 7. 4th cable to the rescue.